Issues due to openzeppelin updated versions
Im building defi token Im developing it with reference cource in which the educator is using openzeppelin version 4.8.3 in which ERC20Mock contract takes 4 parameters , but right now there is only version 5.0.2 of openzepplin is available in which ERC20Mock.sol takes only 2 parameters.
Here is the HelperConfig script code that Patrick used:
import { ERC20Mock } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/mocks/ERC20Mock.sol";

        vm.startBroadcast();
        MockV3Aggregator ethUsdPriceFeed = new MockV3Aggregator(DECIMALS, ETH_USD_PRICE);
        ERC20Mock wethMock = new ERC20Mock("WETH", "WETH", msg.sender, 1000e8);

        MockV3Aggregator btcUsdPriceFeed = new MockV3Aggregator(DECIMALS, BTC_USD_PRICE);
        ERC20Mock wbtcMock = new ERC20Mock("WBTC", "WBTC", msg.sender, 1000e8);
        vm.stopBroadcast();
        

And this is the ERC20Mock.sol contract in the latest latest openzeppelin v5.0.2
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {ERC20} from "../../token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract ERC20Mock is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("ERC20Mock", "E20M") {}

    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }

    function burn(address account, uint256 amount) external {
        _burn(account, amount);
    }
}

Can someone help me figure out how i can resolve this issue ?

There are multiple ways you can handle this, don't try to copy the tutorial as it is.

Just remove those two unwanted arguments from the script.
     ERC20Mock wbtcMock = new ERC20Mock("WBTC", "WBTC");


Use the previous version of OZ, where it takes 4 parameters.

Just create your mock contract and include 4 parameters in it, if you don't wanna use an older version of OZ.


